# How to make admin approve user in ionic 3?

Tags: laravel, ionic3, laragon

There are three user roles for my current ionic apps. First is customer, clinic, and doctor.

What I want to do now is I want the doctor to be able to register for the clinic. Which mean, which clinic the doctor work. After the doctor register for the clinic, there must be some approval needed for the clinic to approve the doctor.

What idea I have thought for now is about generating qr code. Which mean only the doctor get the qr code from the clinic and register as doctor for the clinic.

What do I want to ask is there any other way to register the doctor to the clinic?
How to make the clinic to approve the doctor.

Answer (score 1):

You tag "laravel", so I think you can use a restful api solution.
In the app the doctor choose the clinic (maybe with your qr code, o maybe a simple ID for the clinic) and send the approval request via API, sending medic ID ad clinic ID.
Your server manage the request (saving it on a DB) and then send a notification to the clinic. 
The clinic accept or deny the request on the app or in a web page.